# Listview does not match the content and how to position it

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, switch-statement

In this position of the switch does not match with list view after search/filter, how to get real position of list view after filter it.

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

switch (position)
```

[Array 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xist.jpg)

[But The Contents is Array 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOXun.jpg)

```
public class CariTroubleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ListView listView;
Intent intent;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
String[] daftar = {"1","2"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cari_trouble);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.cariTrouble);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, daftar);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    intent = new Intent(CariTroubleActivity.this, MasalahActivity.class);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_cari, menu);
    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuCari);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String list) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(list);
            return false;
        }
    });


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}



@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    switch (position){

        case 0 :

            intent.putExtra("Tit", "Error Code");
            intent.putExtra("text1","Title 1");
            intent.putExtra("text2","Error 1ccccc");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 1 :

            intent.putExtra("Tit", "Error Code");
            intent.putExtra("text1","Title 2");
            intent.putExtra("text2","Error 2cccc");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Listview does not match the content, after the filter listview. then how to adjust the position of listview with the position of the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your list is filtered, you can not directly use `position` anymore (because the first item `position==0` is now the first item of your filter etc.

So, you can override the `BaseAdapter` and create a logic to handle that list, or, since you are using basic adapters, you can just try to figure out the `position` in a different way:

Here:

```
String[] daftar = {"1","2"};
```

So, the text `"1"` and `"2"` will be used as content of your `ListView`. That list is using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1` which is just a `TextView`.

This way, you can just read the `TextView` content instead of `position`:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String textDisplayedByCurrentItem = ((TextView) view).getText();

    if(textDisplayedByCurrentItem.equals(daftar[0]) { // or .equals("1")
            intent.putExtra("Tit", "Error Code");
            intent.putExtra("text1","Title 1");
            intent.putExtra("text2","Error 1ccccc");
            startActivity(intent);
    } else if (textDisplayedByCurrentItem.equals(daftar[1]) {  // or .equals("2")
            intent.putExtra("Tit", "Error Code");
            intent.putExtra("text1","Title 2");
            intent.putExtra("text2","Error 2cccc");
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: then what if i have 200 data array ?? would not it be efficient if I use if-else??

Comment: You can convert textDisplayedByCurrentItem to a number and use in a switch case.. Integer.parseInt(textDisplayedByCurrentItem);